# Is there anything like perl's Regexp::Grammars or labeled subpatterns in .NET?

Tags: .net, regex, perl, regexp-grammars

I really like perl's [Regexp::Grammars](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Regexp-Grammars-1.016/lib/Regexp/Grammars.pm) module. Is there anything like this for .NET?

I'd really like to use a recursive descent parser in a regex style way (eg searching for a matching pattern through a large document) in C#, and be able to express that pattern recursively.

**Update** After reading this [little gem](http://web.archive.org/web/20120814085314/http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1479) from brian d foy, I discovered that perl 5.10 supports labeled subpatterns using (?&NAME). [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) now has a [Nuget package](https://nuget.org/packages/pcre/), and PCRE supports named/labeled subpatterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl5 Regexp::Grammars is modeled after [Perl6 grammars](http://enwp.org/Perl_6_rules#Grammars).

[Niecza](http://enwp.org/Niecza) is a Perl6 implementation that [implements grammars](http://perl6.org/compilers/features#Grammars) and targets the [CLI](http://enwp.org/Common_Language_Infrastructure), which .NET also does.

Comment: interesting. I wonder if I could create a .NET class or DLL using Niecza and then call it from c#?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a comparable module, but you *can* create recursive regexes in .NET. [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002605/regex-embedded-matching/6002694#6002694).