# Regex replace content within parenthesis ignoring nested parenthesis

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following line

```
(textMsg).Style.set_BackgroundColor(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));
```

and what I want to get is

```
(textMsg).Style.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
```

i tried with the following regEx pattern but with no luck

```
set_(.*)\((([^()]*|(?R))*)\)
```

i would appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: `(@R)` is a Perl/PCRE-specific recurse-whole-pattern expression. .NET also handles recursion but uses a different syntax. See: [regex embedded {{ matching](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6002694/433790) and substitute parentheses for curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this instead:

```
set_([^(]*)\((.*)\)
```

This captures the property name after `set_` in group `$1` and anything between the `(` and `)` of the method call into group `$2, so you can use a replacement string like this:

```
$1 = $2
```

**[Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/lV9gF9)**

Your expression is invalid and won't compile because you have unbalanced parentheses and un-recongnized tokens.